# Show that $\|u\|_p = \max \left\{ |\langle u,v\rangle| \ \text{s.t.}\ \|v\|_q \le 1 \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have proved Holders inequality:

$$ |\langle u,v\rangle| \le \|u\|_p \|v\|_q$$

And I know that we have equality when (for all $i$):

$$ \frac{|u_i|^p}{{\|u\|_p}^{p}} = \frac{|v_i|^q}{{\|v\|_q}^{q}}$$

However I'm not having difficulty proving the following:

$\|u\|_p = \max \left\{ |\langle u,v\rangle| \ \text{s.t.} \  \|v\|_q \le 1 \right\}$

I'm trying to use the equality condition to say that $\|u\|_p = \frac{|\langle u,v\rangle |}{\|v\|_q}$ but then I'm not sure where the maximum comes in?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hölder's inequality shows that your right-hand-side is less than or equal than the left. Also,
$$
\|u\|_p=\left\langle u, \frac {s|u|^{p-1}}{\|u\|_p^{p-1}}\right\rangle,
$$
where $ s $ changes signs where appropriate.
Now all you need to check is that $\left\|\frac {u^{p-1}}{\|u\|_p^{p-1}}\right\|_q=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit confused by your notation though, what do you mean by $u^{p-1}$?

Comment: I mean the $ p-1$ power of $ u $.

Comment: But $u$ is a vector?

Comment: You never said so, one usually talks functions when dealing with $ p $-norms. But it is the same: you can see vectors in $\mathbb R^n $ as functions $ u:\{1,2,\ldots, n\}\to\mathbb R $. In any case, $ u^k $ means "the vector with entries the $ k^{\rm th} $ powers of the entries of $ u $".

Comment: Ah yes sorry, of course, that makes sense now!

Comment: Note also that you need to take signs into account. If you write an example with $ n=2$ you'll see it.

Comment: I've been thinking for a while about this - I can see that this $v$ does what you said it does, but I can't see how this would solve the problem? If you could give me some hints for this that would be great.

Comment: Said $v$ gives you a vector where you get the equality holds: $\|u\|_p=|\langle u,v\rangle|$ for that specific $v$. This shows that $$\|u\|_p\leq\max\{|\langle u,v\rangle|: \ \|v\|_q=1\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

There exist a $v=\left(\frac{|u|}{||u||_p}\right)^{\frac{p}{q}}$ with $||v||_q=1$ and $|\langle u,v \rangle |=||u||_p$.